# Find a data-attribute within a class that is equal to a variable

Tags: javascript

Please no jquery
Im trying to delete an element inside list with the same data-id as foo

```
let foo = document.querySelector('.foo');
let list = document.querySelector('.listing-filter');
let fooId = foo.dataset.id;
let listId = list.dataset.id;

let listingFilter = () => {
    if ( typeof fooId !== 'undefined' && typeof listId !== 'undefined'){
        //This is what I cant seem to figure out
        let deleteMe = document.querySelector('.listing-filter[data-id = fooId]')

        //This should only be the data-id in list that changes not in el1
        deleteMe.setAttribute('data-id', 'hidden')
     }
}
```

Then in css i can select it [data-id="hidden"] and hide the element.

I cant seem to figure out how to select in list the list element that has the same data-id as foo, and then manipulate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've typed in `fooId` directly, so it'll look for something with `data-id="fooId"` rather than your defined `fooId` value. Try adding your variable to the string:

```
let deleteMe = document.querySelector(`.listing-filter[data-id=${fooId}]`)
```

Comment: I'm using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which use backtick's (\`) but you can also do `data-id=' + fooId + ']"'`

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector('.listing-filter[data-id="fooId"]')
```

Could you try updating your query selector string?

Comment: This won't work, it's still hardcoding `fooId` as the `data-id` value

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there:

```
let deleteMe = document.querySelector('.listing-filter [data-id="' + fooId + '"]');
```

Moreover you don't need `.foo`

```
let list = document.querySelector('.listing-filter');
let listId = list.dataset.id;

let listingFilter = () => {
    if (typeof listId !== 'undefined'){
      let deleteMe = document.querySelector('.listing-filter [data-id="' + listId + '"]');
      deleteMe.setAttribute('data-id', 'hidden')
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the documentation for the `let listingFilter = () => {` syntax, I'd like to read up on it?  Also the whole `let` thing as I'm used to just creating `vars`

Comment: @AlexanderDixon, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)